# Xiaomi HM 1SW java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, android, proguard

I see a strange crash with next line:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.EqualsBuilder.a
```

Yes, I use proguard to obfuscate but I don't see same crash on other devices that I have with me. As well I unpacked apk and see that this class with this method is present.

I have assumption:

1. Someone is playing with apk
2. Something weird with device - particularly with ClassLoader

Unfortunately I can not verify my assumptions since I don't have physical access to this device.

Maybe you have experienced such error or you have additional information that brings a light on the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried the `-keep class` solution and it worked, but it did get the APK method count higher in about 3K methods.

A better solution is

`-keepnames class org.apache.commons.lang3.** { *; }`

As it will keep the classes/methods names that you use, avoiding the crash, but will allow for the unused ones to be removed.

Comment: Cool! Accepting your answer now

Answer (score 2):

**claim:** I do not know the source of the problem.

I've encounter this issue and worked around it by telling ProGuard not to obfuscate Apache Commons lib.

`-keep class org.apache.commons.lang3.** { *; }`

Comment: Jose, thanks for answer. It is workaround indeed. Can you confirm that the issue fixed? Can you confirm that rest of the code doesn't produce same issue again?

Comment: Eugen, I've only been able to test with one Xiaomi Device and all good. That said, I can not confirm if something equal or similar wont show again  as I am not able to understand the root cause.

Comment: Thanks a lot! What is device name?

Comment: Accepting as temporary solution this answer and looking for cause and proper fix. Thanks Jose!

Comment: Have you found a proper solution? I've the same problem, with Xiaomi Redmi and `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.join`. Keeping whole Apache Commons in APK is not a good solution and against the idea of ProGuard.